# SSH in the most convenient way without typing in the ssh command everytime

Tags: macos, ssh

I constantly need to log into a remote server and do all kinds of work. I am using my Mac and every time I have to type in a long command to do that.

```
ssh -i ~/key.pem ubuntu@255.255.255.255
```

I am wondering what would be the easiest way to log into the remote server without typing in the command everyday.

Handy apple apps are also welcome

Updated:

1> Thanks to Matt Bryant's answer. I successfully avoided typing in the whole username and host address by modifying ~/.ssh/config (doesn't exist as default) to

```
Host <ShortName>
    User <UserName>
    HostName <HostIP>
    IdentityFile <KeyPath>
```

then I could just type this command to avoid typing in the full name of host and full path of the key:

```
ssh <ShortName>
```

2> Anyone knows how to store the pem key or avoid typing in the password if there is no pem key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ~/.ssh/config file.  Try adding the following to it:

```
Host server                                                                                                  
    User ubuntu
    HostName 255.255.255.255
```

This will allow you to login using `ssh -i ~/key.pem server`.  If you look up ssh config, there are many other settings that will allow you to simplify and enhance your ssh experience.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, is it possible to avoid typing in the pem key permanently?

Comment: that is so cool! so if there is no pem key and it is password required. You just simply add something like PassWord?

Comment: nope.. password don't work like that - if it requires a password you could write an expect script to wrap around the call. What you could if allowed is ssh-copy-id from host a to host b which copies the pub to the authorised keys on the other side and makes it a key connection from there on

Comment: @vahid Sounds hard and interesting. And you send me a link to some tutorials etc. I could take a try?

Comment: It is considered **terrible** practice to leave passwords in plaintext like that, but if you really want to do it and know that no one else will ever use your machine, `expect` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Hi B MR W yes I am going to post up an expect script since this comes up a lot:

**E2A The instructions are for linux**
There is expect on mac https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html
It might be mean messing with the script to meet the criteria of the mac expect I don't have enough knowledge on that but in principal having had a look the below process should work

Which bit was you interested in the ssh-copy-id or a script?

to get a script going you need to

```
sudo-apt-get install expect or 
sudo yum install expect
```

Once installed

This is a typical script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


set force_conservative 1  
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .001}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .001
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

;# Validate user input - make sure all fields required are given 
if {$argc >= 1} {
    ;# Setting  password
    set user "MYUSER";
    set supass "MYPASSWORD"

    set host [lindex $argv 0]
  #     set command1 [lindex $argv 2]

   set prompt "(:|#|%|>|\\\$|% |# |> |\\\$ )"
   set prompt1 "(>)"
   set timeout -1
   ;###############################################################

   ;#connect to specified host given by addstaff or globalstaff.
   spawn ssh $user@$host
   expect { 
        "*word:*" {}
        "*(yes/no)?*" {
                      send - "yes\r" 
                  expect "*word:" { }

                  } 
       }          

   send  - "$supass\r"
  expect eof exit -re $prompt

   send -  "sudo bash\r"
   expect   {
                 "*word:*" {
                         send  "$supass\r"
                         expect  eof exit -re $prompt
                 }
        "*" {  
              expect eof exit -re $prompt
        }

   }

    send  - "whoami\r"
        expect eof exit -re $prompt

    interact 

    ;#send  - "$command\r"
    ;#  expect eof exit -re $prompt

    ;#Logout of current ssh session
    ;#send  - "exit\r"
    ;#expect eof exit -re $prompt

    ;#send  - "exit\r"
    ;#expect eof exit -re $prompt


} else {
  send - "echo Sorry require user host command \n\n\r";
  exit
}
```

If you have noticed I have commented out the commands which is not being sent - its using interact mode to allow you to actually log in without  a password, user password defined at the top of the script... Once logged in you type as you would per normal ssh

Here is me running it locally:

```
 whoami
myuser
./ssh-connection.exp localhost
spawn ssh myuser@localhost
myuser@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux XXXX)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Sat Sep  7 20:19:53 2013 from localhost
sudo bash
This is BASH 4.2- DISPLAY on localhost:0.0

Sat Sep  7 20:25:09 BST 2013
whoami
[20:25 myuser@myuser-DP ~] > sudo bash
whoami
This is BASH 4.2- DISPLAY on localhost:0.0

Sat Sep  7 20:25:09 BST 2013
[20:25 myuser@myuser-DP ~] > whoami
root
[20:25 myuser@myuser-DP ~] > whoami
root
```

Within the script it also does a sudo bash which is why it reconnects me to localhost and I become root

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. That is indeed a lot of new and interesting stuff. I will take a close look first and then comment back to you if I have further question.

Comment: cool Mr W I will try to help the best I can.. for a start I can see on the mac install the path for expect would be different, if this is all correct the first line should be #!/usr/local/bin/expect -f. Once installed run a which expect to find true path and amend accordingly